# Solving $\sin(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)\tan(\beta) = -a\frac{\tan(\beta)}{b}$ for $\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

I haven't practiced trigonometry for a while, and I'm wondering if there's a way to solve this analytically:

$$\sin(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)\tan(\beta) = -a\frac{\tan(\beta)}{b}$$

I'm solving for $\alpha$, so $\beta$, $a$ and $b$ are known.

If there is, can someone point out the right way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the cosine term to the other side:$$\sin(\alpha)=\cos(\alpha)\tan(\beta)  -a\frac{\tan(\beta)}{b}$$
Now square the equation (you will need to check if this introduce additional solutions)
$$\sin^2(\alpha)=1-\cos^2\alpha=\left(\cos(\alpha)\tan(\beta)  -a\frac{\tan(\beta)}{b}\right)^2$$
You can see now that you have a quadratic equation in $\cos\alpha$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I arrive to $$\frac{\frac{a}{b}tan^2 \beta \pm \sqrt(\tan^2 \beta (1-\frac{a^2}{b^2})+1)}{tan^2 \beta + 1}$$. The result for my problem isn't exactly what I was expecting but it is close enough. I'll take a closer look to see if I did something wrong, thanks!

Comment: Yes it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve $\sin(x)+u\cos(x)+v=0$. Writing $\cos(x)=y+y^{-1}$, $\sin(x)=\frac{y-y^{-1}}{i}$ with $y=e^{ix}$, giving you a degree two polynomial equation.$$
\frac{y-y^{-1}}{i} + u(y+y^{-1})+v=0
$$
So
$$
y^2(u-i)+yv+(u+i)=0
$$
I think you can finish yourself.